Unable to display canvas element in my game
This is my code for my game project and it does not display the canvas on the screen. Even if I inspect the webpage it is still not there. I really don't know what the problem is.
I tried changing or resizing the CSS, and also the JS especially below where you create and initialize the character. It actually works for the other character but it does not work for the enemy character. I tried copying the other character but the canvas is still not showing up
<div id="enemy-area" class="enemy-area">
  <canvas id="enemy-canvas"></canvas>
  <div id="ea-1" class="ea"></div>
  <div id="ea-2" class="ea"></div>
</div>

#enemy-area {
  display: grid;
  position: relative;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(20vh, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 35vh;
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

#enemy-canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  z-index: 20;
  pointer-events: none;
}

import Character from './Character.js';

export default class Enemy extends Character {
  constructor(name, maxHP, HP, defense, imageSrc, healthBarId, team, type, statusHP, ATK, temporaryATK, temporaryDEF) {
    super(name, maxHP, HP, defense, imageSrc, healthBarId, team, type, statusHP, ATK, temporaryATK, temporaryDEF);

    this.name = name || 'Enemy';
    this.maxHP = maxHP || 12;
    this.HP = HP || 12;
    this.defense = defense || 0;
    this.imageSrc = imageSrc || '../texture/CHARACTER/enemy1.png';
    this.healthBarId = healthBarId || 'enemy-health-bar';
    this.team = team || 'enemy-area';
    this.type = type || 'enemy-object';
    this.statusHP = statusHP || 'enemy-hp';
    this.ATK = ATK || 0;
    this.temporaryATK = temporaryATK || 0;
    this.temporaryDEF = temporaryDEF || 0;

    // Animation properties
    this.spriteWidth = 64;
    this.spriteHeight = 64;
    this.staggerFrames = 8;
    this.gameFrame = 0;
    this.scale = 2.9;
    this.spriteAnimationsEnemy = {};
    this.animationStates.forEach((state, index) => {
      let frames = {
        loc: []
      };
      for (let j = 0; j < state.frames; j++) {
        let positionX = j * this.spriteWidth;
        let positionY = index * this.spriteHeight;
        frames.loc.push({
          x: positionX,
          y: positionY
        });
      }
      this.spriteAnimationsEnemy[state.name] = frames;
    });

    this.currentAnimation = 'wave,right'; // Default animation

    // Load the sprite sheet
    this.spriteSheet = new Image();
    this.spriteSheet.src = this.imageSrc;
    this.spriteSheet.onload = () => {
      console.log(`Enemy sprite sheet loaded successfully: ${this.spriteSheet.src}`);
    };
    this.spriteSheet.onerror = () => {
      console.error(`Failed to load sprite sheet: ${this.spriteSheet.src}`);
    };

    // Initialize canvas after DOM is ready
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => this.initializeCanvas());
  }

  // Initialize the canvas and its context
  initializeCanvas() {
    this.enemyElement = document.getElementById('enemy-canvas');
    if (!this.enemyElement) {
      console.error("Canvas element for enemy not found. Ensure the HTML contains a canvas with ID 'enemy-canvas'.");
      return;
    }

    console.log(`Canvas element found: ${this.enemyElement.id}`);
    const devicePixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1;
    this.enemyElement.width = this.enemyElement.clientWidth * devicePixelRatio;
    this.enemyElement.height = this.enemyElement.clientHeight * devicePixelRatio;
    this.context = this.enemyElement.getContext('2d');
    if (!this.context) {
      console.error("Failed to initialize 2D context for enemy canvas.");
      return;
    }

    this.context.scale(devicePixelRatio, devicePixelRatio);
    this.context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

    console.log("Canvas and context initialized successfully.");
  }

  // Animate the enemy
  animateEnemy() {
    if (!this.enemyElement || !this.context || !this.spriteSheet.complete) {
      console.error("Animation prerequisites not met. Ensure canvas, context, and sprite sheet are properly initialized.");
      return;
    }

    this.gameFrame++;

    // Get the current animation and frame position
    const animation = this.spriteAnimationsEnemy[this.currentAnimation];
    if (!animation) {
      console.error(`Animation state '${this.currentAnimation}' not found.`);
      return;
    }

    const position = Math.floor(this.gameFrame / this.staggerFrames) % animation.loc.length;
    const frame = animation.loc[position];

    // Clear the canvas
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.enemyElement.width, this.enemyElement.height);

    // Calculate scaled dimensions
    const scaledWidth = Math.round(this.spriteWidth * this.scale);
    const scaledHeight = Math.round(this.spriteHeight * this.scale);

    // Center the image
    const destX = (this.enemyElement.width - scaledWidth) / 2;
    const destY = (this.enemyElement.height - scaledHeight) / 2;

    // Draw the current frame
    this.context.drawImage(
      this.spriteSheet,
      frame.x, frame.y, // Source frame (x, y)
      this.spriteWidth, // Source frame width
      this.spriteHeight, // Source frame height
      destX, destY, // Destination (x, y)
      scaledWidth, // Scaled width
      scaledHeight // Scaled height
    );
  }

  // Initialize the enemy and start animation
  const enemy = new Enemy(
    'Enemy',
    80,
    80,
    0,
    '../texture/CHARACTER/enemy1.png',
    'enemy-health-bar',
    'enemy-object',
    'enemy-hp',
    5,
    0,
    0
  );

  // Main animation loop
  function animate() {
    enemy.animateEnemy(); // Update the enemy's animation
    requestAnimationFrame(animate); // Request the next frame
  }

  // Start the animation loop
  animate();


Not exactly related, but never size a canvas using CSS, it just makes the canvas blurry. Instead, use width and height attributes of the canvas.

If the <canvas> element itself isn't appearing when inspecting with dev tools, you have something fundamentally wrong with either the HTML page or how you are testing it. If you add another element or just some text, does that appear?

In your HTML a closing  is missing. Maybe this lead you to confusion? I assume the canvas goes inside the enemy-area. This works for me on this codesandbox (canvas in blue) https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/xz8jgt

Open browser devtools (press F12) and check the console for errors.

Are you getting your own "not found" error in the console? It might just be that you instantiate the class before the DOMContentLoaded event. This tends to happen if you put your script in the <head> and not defer its execution until page load. We cannot say that for sure though, as your code isn't complete in that regard. Also, consider converting your code to an SO snippet so we can test ourselves inside this page. It's that <> button when editing your post.
